# Visual Studio 2010 Unit Testing: Referenced Project Class Not Being Recognized

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a basic unit test for a very basic C++ class in Visual Studio 2010. I have already tested the class and everything works. However, when I make a Test Project, I can't get the class to be recognized.

My class header file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef FIRST_H
#define FIRST_H
class First
{
private:
string name;
int age;
public:
// Constructors
First(); // default constructor
First(string n, int a); // constructor with parameters

void ChangeAge(int newAge);
void ChangeName(string newName);

void getName();
void getAge();
};
#endif
```

My Class cpp file:

```
#include "First.h"

// Constructors
First :: First()// default constructor
{
    name = "No Name";
    age = 0;
}
First :: First(string n, int a) // constructor with parameters
{
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
//Manipulators
void First :: ChangeAge(int newAge)
{
    age = newAge;
}
void First :: ChangeName(string newName)
{
    name = newName;
}
// Observers
void First :: getName()
{
    cout << "The name of this student is " << name << endl;
    //cin >> name;
}
void First :: getAge()
{
    cout << "The age of this student is " << age << endl;
}
```

Here is my Basic Unit Test:   // Note: All of this is autogenerated, except for the body of void TestMethod1()

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

    namespace TestProject5
    {
        [TestClass]
        public ref class UnitTest1
        {
        public: 
        [TestMethod]
        void TestMethod1()
        {
            First person;    // Sets Age to 0
            person.getAge(); // Should Display 0
        }
    };
}
```

When building the unit Test project, I am getting an error saying:
 "First is an undeclared identifier".

If I change the "public ref class" value from "UnitTest1" to my class name "First", I get the following error:
"'getAge' is not a member of 'TestProject5::First'"

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code or the error messages but include all relevant information as text in your question.

Comment: You are probably missing a `using namespace` directive.  Do also ensure that the First class is in fact a C++/CLI class (a ref class) and that it is public.  And that you actually meant to create a managed unit test, C++/CLI classes don't fit the "very basic C++ class" moniker that well.

Comment: It is your code, I can't see it.  Use Object Browser.

Comment: @HansPassant My "First" Class is not a Ref class. What do I need to do to fix it? --I don't know what a ref class is

Comment: @Capricorn I have the code now. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include "First.h"` in your unit test file.

That said, are you sure you are aiming for C++/CLI?

Comment: When I do this, I get the error: "Cannot open include file: 'First.h': No such file or directory". I don't understand your second question. This project is in C++, what is CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by right clicking my test project, and selecting:
Properties>General>CommonLanguageRuntimeSupport. I then changed “Safe MSIL Common Language RunTime Support (/clr:safe)”    to    “Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)”. 
Afterwards, I was still getting errors, so I changed my ref class name from back to the default name generated. I also removed "namespace TestProject5" as well as the braces. This fixed ALL of my errors.

Here is my new Code:

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "First.cpp"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

//namespace TestProject4

    [TestClass]
    public ref class UnitTest5
    {
    public: 
        [TestMethod]
        void TestMethod1()
        {
            First person;
            int age = person.getAge();
            Assert.AreEqual(0, age);
        }
    };
```

---